# Scheduling App with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I was thinking about building a scheduling/time tabling app with Node JS that is primarily used in/as a mobile native app. Im certain I have worded the specifications wrong, but I was hoping for some guidance on where to start researching:

- Any useful libraries/services
- The general way to go about using Node JS for mobile
- Anything you might think it useful

Thanks!

Comment: This is not what SO is for, this is not the place to ask for libraries or that kind of general guidance.

Comment: Well the question is asking how to implement an Idea at a high level. Obviously there are multiple ways to do this, hence the open ended question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to launch this mobile app natively on multiple platforms (IOS/Android/WP).

If that's the case, you can directly go for hybrid app frameworks which will help you write once and deploy natively on multiple devices. The best two hybrid frameworks that I found are [**React Native**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) and [**Xamarin**](https://www.xamarin.com/) ( different people can have different opinions about different hybrid frameworks )

React Native will give you the opportunity to use JSX which is very close to Javascript. While in Xamarin you'll work purely in C#.

As far as your question regarding deploying natively via node.js is concerned, I don't think it's possible. If you read [**this**](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/brian-rinaldi/build-mobile-apps-with-ja_b_6786920.html) blog post. It says the following.

> Technically, you can run Node on Android, but not iOS. This is because Node uses Google’s V8 JavaScript engine. The V8 engine compiles JavaScript to a native code before executing it, a process known as Just-In-Time (JIT) compiling. iOS does not allow JIT compiling unless the device is jailbroken which why Node applications cannot be deployed native on iOS.
>    Obviously, any mobile strategy that ignores iOS is doomed to fail

So my suggestion would be to use one of these hybrid frameworks for front end and build a node.js based backend service where you can write a REST API to retrieve results for calls you make from the frontend.

There are tons of tutorials out there regarding how to build REST API's in node.js. [**this**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm) can be a good start.

Comment: Thank you! This has been really helpful!